# How often is an item in a purchase?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to calculate how often an item appears in a shopping cart.
I have a purchase recognizable by the `buyerid`. This buyerid can buy several items (also twice, triple,..., n-th times). Recognizable by `itemid` and `description`.
I would like to count the number of times an item ends up in a shopping cart. For example, out of 5 purchases, 3 people bought an apple, i.e. 0.6%. I would like to spend this on all products, how do I do that?

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'buyerid': [0,0,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],
     'itemid': [0,1,2,1,1,1,2,4,5,1,1],
     'description': ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Strawberry', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Dog-Food', 'Beef', 'Banana', 'Apple'], }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
display(df.head(20))
```

[image]

My try:

```
# How many % of the articels are the same?
# this is wrong... :/
df_grouped = df.groupby('description').count()
display(df_grouped)

df_apple = df_grouped.iloc[0]
percentage = df_apple[0] / df.shape[0]
print(percentage)

[OUT] 0.45454545454545453
```

The mathematic formula

```
count of all buys (count_buy ) = 5
count how many an apple appears in the buy (count_apple) = 3
count_buy /count_apple =  3 / 5 = 0.6
```

What I would like to have (please note, I have not calculated the values, these are just dumy values)

[image]

Comment: Is correct `count of all buys (count_buy ) = 4` ? It is `4` ?

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for asking. Unfortunately not! There are 5 purchases ... totally overlooked that, thanks!  If we count the unique `buyerid`s we get 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and divide by count of unique values of `buyerid` by [`Series.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['itemid','description']).size())
itemid  description
0       Banana         1
1       Apple          3
        Banana         2
        Strawberry     1
2       Apple          2
4       Dog-Food       1
5       Beef           1
dtype: int64


purch = df['buyerid'].nunique()
df1 = df.groupby(['itemid','description']).size().div(purch).reset_index(name='percentage')
print (df1)
   itemid description  percentage
0       0      Banana         0.2
1       1       Apple         0.6
2       1      Banana         0.4
3       1  Strawberry         0.2
4       2       Apple         0.4
5       4    Dog-Food         0.2
6       5        Beef         0.2
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I have a question, why is Dog-Food = 1.0? Shouldn't it be 0.2 because of 1 (only one dog food) / 5 (all purchase) ? :)

Comment: @Aline - I am confused, so need `df.groupby(['itemid','description']).size().div(5)` ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion!
I count the number of times an item appeared, for example the apple in 3 purchases. And then I divide by the total number of all purchases. Do I explain better?

Comment: Thank you for your help! And again sorry for the confusion and thank you very much for the answer !! I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would group it and create a new column as follows:

```
df_grp = df.groupby('description')['buyerid'].sum().reset_index(name='total')
df_grp['percentage'] = (df_grp.total / df_grp.total.sum()) * 100
df_grp
```

Result:

```
description total   percentage
0   Apple       11  39.285714
1   Banana      7   25.000000
2   Beef        4   14.285714
3   Dog-Food    4   14.285714
4   Strawberry  2   7.142857
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You have calculated with the total values, that is, an apple that appears several times in the purchase is also counted several times. I would like to count the article only once.

Answer (score 0):

As always, there are multiple ways to the gold, but i would go over pivoting as following:
Your input:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'buyerid': [0,0,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],
     'itemid': [0,1,2,1,1,1,2,4,5,1,1],
     'description': ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Strawberry', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Dog-Food', 'Beef', 'Banana', 'Apple'], }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

In a next step pivot the data with `buyer_id` as `index` and `description` as columns and replace NA with 0 as such

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(values='itemid', index='buyerid', columns='description', aggfunc='count')
df2 = df2.fillna(0)
```

resulting in

```
description  Apple  Banana  Beef  Dog-Food  Strawberry
buyerid                                               
0              1.0     1.0   0.0       0.0         0.0
1              1.0     0.0   0.0       0.0         0.0
2              0.0     0.0   0.0       0.0         1.0
3              2.0     1.0   0.0       0.0         0.0
4              1.0     1.0   1.0       1.0         0.0
```

calling the mean on the table:

```
df_final = df2.mean()
```

results in

```
description
Apple         1.0
Banana        0.6
Beef          0.2
Dog-Food      0.2
Strawberry    0.2
dtype: float64
```